# How to run command all at once

Tags: bash, centos, tmux

I have a script that looks like this

```
cd /root/signedsh/apps
for i in $(find . -name *_Seyed.ipa) ; do
#echo $i
./sign -k "/root/cert/appX.p12" -m "/root/profile/appX.mobileprovision" -p "udidsigning" -z 9 -o "$i" "$i"
done
```

Now this worked fine for the first 10 files, but now I have 300 files I need to run that ./sign command with

At the moment, it waits for the first command to finish then runs it with the second command (`for i in $(find . -name *_Seyed.ipa) ; do`)

Is there a way it can run all 300 or so at the same time? The server is 48 cores and 256GB ddr4 on a large nvme raid 0 so it shouldn't struggle, I just don't know how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run each command in the background (and don't use `find`):

```
shopt -s globstar
cd /root/signedsh/apps
for i in **/*_Seyed.ipa ; do
  ./sign -k "/root/cert/appX.p12" \
         -m "/root/profile/appX.mobileprovision" \
         -p "udidsigning" -z 9 -o "$i" "$i" &
done
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work, Is there a way to limit it to say 10 at a time?

Comment: A quick way is to add `while (( $(jobs -p) > 10 )); wait -n; done` before call to `sign`. This will cause it to wait for at least 1 job to complete, until no more than 10 are running, before starting a new job.

Comment: You might want to look into using `xargs` or GNU `parallel` instead of the `for` loop, though.